# Disable Counter android

Tags: android, animation, android-mediaplayer, counter

in my application I have a counter that starts at 15, and I have a button that has an animation and sound, the problem is that I want to turn off the sound and the animation of the button and change the background to play another sound on click when the counter reaches 0

this is the code that I tried to lock the meter and the sound but it does not work, I'm using it wrong you have any idea?

code:

```
MediaPlayer  mediaPlayer;
    int contatore;
    TextView Display;
    Button b1;


    private StartAppAd startAppAd = new StartAppAd(this);


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.b1);

        contatore = 15;
        b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
        Display = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.contatore);



        final Animation animRotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.pistola);


        b1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() { 



            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                      contatore --;
                      Display.setText(""+contatore);

                  for (int contatore = 0; contatore!= 0; ){
                          contatore = (Integer) null;
                          mediaPlayer = null;
                         }



                arg0.startAnimation(animRotate);
                final Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);

                button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.deserteagle_1);
                Handler handler = new Handler(); 
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
                     public void run() { 
                         button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.deserteagle_0); 
                     } 
                }, 100); 


                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.b1);
                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            mediaPlayer.start();

                            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                                    mediaPlayer.release();

                                };
                            });
                                }
                            });
            }

        });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Explain again what "doesn't work". You mean the counter never changes, or the sound source never changes?

Comment: the counter does not stop, and the application works normally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem of the counter in this way, now only remains for me to play another sound instead of this and stop the animation and change the background of the button

```
private int contatore = 15;
            private Object mediaPlayer;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                      contatore --;
                      Display.setText(""+contatore);

                      if(this.contatore <= 0)
                {
                        this.contatore=1;
                          this.mediaPlayer = null;
                         }
```

Comment: Might be better if you could update the code in your original post...
And ya, I'm just not quite sure what exactly you're trying to do here.
You start the counter at 15, then when it's 0 you set it back to 1?

Answer (score 0):

Ok...from looking at your code, try these changes.

This:

```
final Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.deserteagle_1);
```

To this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  // you already have `b1` that points to `R.id.b1`, so use that
  // instead of using `findViewById` again
  b1.setBackgroundResource(...);
});
```

I'm not sure what this part is supposed to do:

```
          for (int contatore = 0; contatore!= 0; ){
                  contatore = (Integer) null;
                  mediaPlayer = null;
                 }
```

Also be sure to wrap that `Display.setText` inside `runOnUiThread`